# Windows application to notify me when my external IP changes?

Tags: windows, ip, google-analytics

I am watching web traffic to one of my sites via Google Analytics.  I have created a filter to exclude data from my ipaddress.

I'm pretty sure my ISP will change that address from time to time; making the filter no good.

Is there a little app (or script) that can run in the background and notify me when my external IP Address changes?

Comment: If you are using a router then what you want is not possible because your computer is never actually assigned a new ipaddress your modem is ( which your router is aware of ).

Comment: Using a filter from within Google Analytics is the wrong approach, in my opinion. The filter should be on your computer or browser to block the GA script from running when you visit your site.

Comment: @Ramhound -1 :P  "External IP Address"  If your theory were correct, then visiting http://ipchicken.com/ would show me nothing.  I'm looking for something that wraps that functionality into some kind of windows program that will notify me.  Even it if were some hacky program that loaded http://ipchicken.com/ in the background to keep track of it, I would not care.  I just want to save the time and trouble of writing it myself.

Comment: @iglvzx Not in my opinion.  There are periods of development (maybe hours, maybe days) where I will be testing on 3 PCs and 2 smart phones.  It's easier for me to create filter that blocks all devices in my house.

Comment: @iglvzx would a simple block in adblocker do the trick?

Comment: @ray023 in my understanding, uBlock Origin can be installed in Firefox on Android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a project on CodePlex that does this: http://ipchangeinformer.codeplex.com

It notifies via email and can be configured to use a custom webserver for the public IP checks using a PHP file you upload to the desired site. There is also a default site (probably managed by the app author).

Also, DynDNS has a service that does this using an app resident on your computer that checks with DynDNS at regular intervals and updates your DynDNS account if you're trying to host something locally.

Comment: DiogoRocha: I prefer to leave my links completely visible so there's less chance of obfuscation and less reason to fear a hijacked destination page. Thanks for the edit though.

Comment: Is that not the purpose of the browser's status bar/popup? URLs alone are not descriptive. See [To hide links or not to hide links](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3559/to-hide-links-or-not-to-hide-links-that-is-the-question) on Meta.Superuser.

Comment: @iglvzx: Yes, but even the browser's status bar can be spoofed on non-current browsers. And you'll note in the linked Meta Q, there was no decided standard. I have decided that for myself I will leave visible links. Further, some people prefer not to have a status bar visible. Please leave the answer as I posted it. The edits made on this answer are neither substantive or desired unless there is a significant error in the details or a spelling or grammatical mistake I have overlooked.

Comment: how do I run the program? I download the archive and it's just a bunch of folders and code, no executable file

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option that might help you, I've written a python script designed to monitor for external IP address changes.  Since it's python it should work on Windows just fine after setting up the appropriate Python environment (although I've only tested it under Linux).  It currently saves the "current" external IP address to a file and, when run, grabs a new IP address and then checks it against the old one.  It is design to email you with this change.

It's designed to run as a cronjob (Linux) or scheduled task (Windows) and does not run as a background daemon on its own.

Here's the link to the github repository: https://github.com/begleysm/ipwatch

Hopefully it helps!